# Is there a way to force refresh an android app shortcut icon?

Tags: android, android-studio

Before my last release, I changed the name of the image file used for my app icon. The image is the same, the name has just changed. When the update rolled out, I started getting notification from users that the shortcut icon on their home screen has changed to the default little green android character app icon. The app icon in the app drawer is still intact and if I re-add the shortcut from the app drawer to a home screen, it works as expected with the proper icon. So, back to the title of my question: Is there a way to force refresh an android app shortcut icon? Or maybe to delete and re-add it programmatically upon update?

I can revert the image file name back to what it was before, but that might just perpetuate the problem for all of the new downloads and users who already downloaded updates.

I should state that I'm pretty sure that changing the app icon image file name is what started the problem. If anyone has any insight as to what else might cause the problem, I'd be open to hear that as well.

I develop with Android Studio and my apps are targeted to the HTC One and Galaxy S4/S5 if that makes any difference. Thanks.

Additional requested code:

From app.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 8
    versionName "1.4"
}
```

From R.java:

```
public static final class drawable {
    public static final int appicon =0x7f020000;
```

From AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/appicon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.Fullscreen" >
```

Comment: Did you update your manifest to point to the new image?

Comment: @GabeSechan Yes, I did update the manifest. As I mentioned, the app icon in the app drawer is fine. It is just the shortcut icon that has been affected.

Comment: There are hundreds of home screen applications (both pre-installed by the manufacturer and "aftermarket" ones installed by the user), none of which have to provide you with any capability to do anything regarding shortcuts, let alone refresh them.

Comment: What new name did you use exactly? With what extension if any? Is it a 9 patch and does it pass 9 patch validation? Did you make the change in each dpi folder? Did you increment the version code integer number in your manifest? Did you try cleaning and rebuilding everything? How much time did you wait to make sure the new version you published was actually the latest version you uploaded to Google Play?

Comment: Please also show us your actual relevant code from the manifest. And the relevant code you find in your generated R.java file. We trust you, but we need to verify the basics before we start brainstorming of exotic reasons for your problem. By the way, do you get any errors or warnings in your IDE error pane?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Thanks for all of your questions. Let’s see, I changed the image file name (via refactor>rename) from htcone_icon.png to appicon.png. It is not a 9 patch. I did increment the version code and version name, however, I do this in my app.gradle file and not in my manifest. I did a gradle sync, a clean, and a rebuild before assembling the release version of my apk. I noticed the problem a couple of days after publishing. After receiving the update, a friend let me know what was going on, and some users referred to the issue after “the latest update” in comments on Google Play.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk No errors or warnings. I included the code you requested in my original post. Hopefully it helps. You know what? After pasting that code, I just realized that I was playing around with the Android L Preview SDK version 20 and I never changed it back to 19. Possible this could be the problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare Do home screen app icons change automatically when an app is updated and the launcher icon has changed? Is this something that the vanilla android home screen does?

Comment: Beats me -- I haven't tried changing the icon associated with a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

If incrementing `android:versionCode` from your manifest doesn't solve your issue, then it could just be a dpi issue.

The only difference between the home screen vs. the other locations is that the icons on the home screen are sometimes shown with an extra level of dpi.

In other words, if "HTC One" is [supposed to be](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/list-of-android-devices-with-pixel-density-buckets/) xhdpi, make sure that you also have the right icon for xxhdpi (in the case its home screen uses that). Or if yours is an "HTC One S" with the density of hdpi, make sure you also have the right icon for xhdpi (in case the home screen uses that).

```
HTC One                 |      4.2        |  xhdpi
HTC One S               |      4.0        |  hdpi
HTC One X               |      4.0        |  xhdpi
HTC One X+              |      4.1        |  xhdpi
HTC One V               |      4.0        |  hdpi
```

Comment: I’m admittedly (and maybe unwisely) only using one pixel density (drawable-xhdpi) for my app launcher icon. It is my understanding that Android will automatically scale images when they aren’t available in different pixel density buckets. I know that the home screen icons scale when added originally from the add drawer.